# Combinations of different letters in specific positions

Tags: bash, shell-script, command, string

In Unix, I am trying to create all possible combinations of these letter at 6 specific positions as follows:

- Position 1 - A or B or C
- Position 2 - A or C
- Position 3 - only C
- Position 4 - A or D
- Position 5 - B or C
- Position 6 - C or A

So, for example, the combinations could be AACABC, BACABC,...

Is there a quick way how UNIX-tools can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The requirements correspond to the brace expansion

```
{A,B,C}{A,C}C{A,D}{B,C}{C,A}
```

This expands to 48 strings (48 = 3*2*1*2*2*2 ):

```
$ printf '%s\n' {A,B,C}{A,C}C{A,D}{B,C}{C,A}
AACABC
AACABA
AACACC
AACACA
AACDBC
AACDBA
AACDCC
AACDCA
ACCABC
ACCABA
ACCACC
ACCACA
ACCDBC
ACCDBA
ACCDCC
ACCDCA
BACABC
BACABA
BACACC
BACACA
BACDBC
BACDBA
BACDCC
BACDCA
BCCABC
BCCABA
BCCACC
BCCACA
BCCDBC
BCCDBA
BCCDCC
BCCDCA
CACABC
CACABA
CACACC
CACACA
CACDBC
CACDBA
CACDCC
CACDCA
CCCABC
CCCABA
CCCACC
CCCACA
CCCDBC
CCCDBA
CCCDCC
CCCDCA
```

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a job for nested `for`-loops:

```
#!/bin/bash

for p1 in A B C; do
  for p2 in A C; do
    for p3 in C; do
      for p4 in A D; do
        for p5 in B C; do
          for p6 in C A; do
            echo "$p1$p2$p3$p4$p5$p6"
          done
        done
      done
    done
  done
done
```

There may be external tools which make this more elegant, but this way is "100% bash" and thus rather portable.

Comment: Wow, 2 seconds after ONE user deletes, this is posted as replacement. Are you all one single person? (AdminBee, Freddy, all the rest )

Comment: Hmmm, now you have found out our secret. How ... _unfortunate_ ;)

Comment: No I have not. I do not know WHY.

Comment: Freddy had overlooked the "all", but I mean another WHY.

Comment: @rastafile Why? My answer was obviously wrong and I should have read the question more carefully.